# How can I derive a Q&A from an existing Q&A in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, javascript

I've been wanting to derive a question from an existing question because the current question is close, but maybe it is missing a specific aspect I am interested in using in my programs.  Should I just create a new question and then put a link to the original questions, or should I just make a new question altogether. Maybe this is too much for a change in the current API?

One example is how do you convert a Int to a String in JavaScript. Well, I want to know how to do just the opposite, or maybe error handling. I think it would be nice if I could clump certain types of questions by hitting a derive question from this question. Or maybe I'm off my rocker :).

Comment: How to convert a string to an int in Javascript is easily answered with a routine Google search (it is the `parseInt()` function).  Those kinds of questions are not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: How do I create an expert system from a disorganized filing system?  Or what steps would it take to train an ai system to determine if an existing question existed and how would it determine if a question can be considered to be derived from an existing question.  Use your stepper intellect around that one.

Answer (score 4):

> One example is how do you convert a Int to a String in javascript. Well I want to know how to do just the reverse, or maybe error handling

This is a *terrible* example! This is a very, very basic question and I'm fairly certain your question is a duplicate of :

- [trying to change string -> int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322935/trying-to-change-string-int)
- [how to parse string to int in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194092/how-to-parse-string-to-int-in-javascript)
- [javascript string and int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883143/javascript-string-and-int)
- [What is the difference between parseInt() and Number()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/string-to-int-use-parseint-or-number)
- [How can I test if a value is a string or an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438701/how-can-i-test-if-a-value-is-a-string-or-an-int)
- [Get the first Int(s) in a string with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609574/get-the-first-ints-in-a-string-with-javascript)
- [How do I convert a string to an int in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504927/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-javascript)
- Or one of [over 3,600 other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+%22string%22+int&submit=search)!

Now, there *are* valid cases I can think of where you can do what you're proposing but they'd need to be a **lot** more complicated than this. As Tim Post very wisely said:

> However, do take care to do some research first, before asking a question. That goes for asking a new question, or asking for something a little different than a previous question covered [...] If you are 'forking' an existing question, it would probably be a good idea to document where you looked, what you tried, etc.

He's absolutely correct. So if you have a question that is almost exactly the same as an existing question but with one small difference **and you really can't find the answer after searching**, then ask your new question, linking to the other question and *showing all the research you did explaining why you still need help*. Remember as soon as you say "I have the same question as [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111099/how-can-i-derive-a-qa-from-an-existing-qa-in-stackoverflow)..." people are going to want to close. So you'll need to make a clear case as to what's different with your question and why it is not  duplicate.

Interestingly enough that's the exact same thing you'll need to do to get your question actually answered, otherwise you'll just get the same answers from the other question ;-)

Comment: Seriously, I took the absolute simplest example possible and put on here to explain a problem of average complexity.  If I had put in a very complex problem I doubt that anyone would have responded.  Its pretty much a given that the architects of Stack Overflow use javascript quite a lot so that why I stuck with simple a simple javascript example and not a UI example.

Comment: Well as long as it's a much more complicated example then you gave, it's fine to ask a second question as long as you follow the guidelines Tim gave.

Comment: Actually this is one of those questions where you need to not look at the question.  The question is pretty much irrelevant here.  The question is really asking how do I get stackoverflow to change there current model so it allows sub-question, or questions related to an original question.  Yes I know it currently doesn't but that's why hackers are in meta and not orderly single file mentats.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying. As Tim Post explained, you *can* ask questions related to an existing question, *as long as you actually have a different question than the original*.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new question, citing the question that didn't answer your question with *great* detail as to why it didn't answer your question. Make sure you read your question before posting it. Is there any way it could be interpreted as basically the same question, just asked differently?

However, do take care to do some research *first*, before asking a question. That goes for asking a new question, or asking for something a little different than a previous question covered.

The whole point of asking a question is to get help from the community. Doing your research first *really* helps to bring you closer to that goal. Not doing any research at all, especially on a very basic question will probably result in an *adverse* reaction, which isn't much help to anyone. If you are 'forking' an existing question, it would probably be a good idea to document where you looked, what you tried, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should do a little more research.